# ANTLR4.7: rule XXX contains a closure with at least one alternative that can match an empty string'

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to create a grammar to match content like below:

(For a simple grammar to repro this issue please see **ADD 1**)

```
[Defines]
  INF_VERSION                    = 0x00010005
  BASE_NAME                      = WebServer
  FILE_GUID                      = 99E87DCF-6162-40c5-9FA1-32111F5197F7
  MODULE_TYPE                    = SEC
  UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION     = 0x00010005
```

**The `UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION     = 0x00010005` part is optional.**

(for brevity, I omitted some of the grammar).

My grammar 1 looks like this:

```
defines : '[Defines]'
         define_statement+
         ;

define_statement  : 'INF_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal 
                  | 'BASE_NAME' EQ BaseName
                  | 'FILE_GUID' EQ RegistryFormatGUID
                  | 'MODULE_TYPE' EQ Edk2ModuleType
                  | ('UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal)?
                  ;
```

ANTLR 4.7 reports this error:

> message: 'rule defines contains a closure with at least one
>   alternative that can match an empty string'

But if I changed grammar like this:

```
defines : '[Defines]'
         define_statement+
         | ('UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal)? // <<< HERE
         ;

define_statement  : 'INF_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal
                  | 'BASE_NAME' EQ BaseName
                  | 'FILE_GUID' EQ RegistryFormatGUID
                  | 'MODULE_TYPE' EQ Edk2ModuleType
```

The error is gone.

My question is, what does the `closure` mean? Which part is the `closure`? The `define_statement`?

After I move the potentially empty alternative, the `defines` rule can alternate between `'[Defines]' define_statement+` and `('UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal)?`, which means `defines` can **still** match empty string. How could the error be gone?

### ADD 1

To make things more clear, I repro this error with a simplified grammar:

```
grammar test;

rule : alternate+; // <<<<< HERE
alternate : '1'?;
```

If I use `+` or `*` at `HERE`, ANTLR will report an **error**:

> 'rule rule contains a closure with at least one alternative that can
>   match an empty string'

If I use `?` at `HERE`, ANTLR will report a **warning**:

> 'rule rule contains an optional block with at least
>   one alternative that can match an empty string'

I am still not sure why.

### ADD 2

Each of the `alternate` WILL be a child node of `rule`, so if `alternate` can be empty string, then it is logically possible to lead to endless child nodes for `rule`. So I guess this may explain why ANTLR forbids me to do that with `alternate+` or `alternate*`. But if it is with `alternate?`, at most there will be **one** child node. It's only a performance issue. So ANTLR just generate a warning.

Comment: Can't answer the question itself, but `define_statement` *can* match an empty string in your example, which looks pointless to me. I'd guess "closure" is `define_statement+`.

Comment: To think, in your grammar `define_statement+` can match an arbitrary number of empty strings, so I guess that's why ANLTR4 complains.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you . But I did that because the `UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION     = 0x00010005` part is optional. Maybe I need to re-design the grammar.

Comment: About `UEFI...`: then your grammar seems completely wrong. What `defines` would match as you wrote is e.g. `[Defines]` plus 10 `INF_VERSION` lines. Sounds like you want something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the warning.  The application is merely alerting you that something can be matched by the empty string.  This is a warning because most of the time, you don't want tokens to match to the empty string.

```
defines : '[Defines]'
         define_statement+
         ;

define_statement  : 'INF_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal 
                  | 'BASE_NAME' EQ BaseName
                  | 'FILE_GUID' EQ RegistryFormatGUID
                  | 'MODULE_TYPE' EQ Edk2ModuleType
                  | ('UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal)?
                  ;
```

Since ('UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal) is optional (it is followed by `?`, it could be replace by nothing, like this:

```
define_statement  : 'INF_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal 
                  | 'BASE_NAME' EQ BaseName
                  | 'FILE_GUID' EQ RegistryFormatGUID
                  | 'MODULE_TYPE' EQ Edk2ModuleType
                  | 
                  ;
```

That last `|` by itself means the rule can match nothing, or the empty string.  So the mystery about the warning is solved.  They call it a closure, but you could think of it as a "token binding" or "match."  I don't think the terminology is all that important in a practical sense.

The error goes away if you remove the alternative, because then, again rewriting for clarity, we have:

```
define_statement  : 'INF_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal 
                  | 'BASE_NAME' EQ BaseName
                  | 'FILE_GUID' EQ RegistryFormatGUID
                  | 'MODULE_TYPE' EQ Edk2ModuleType
                  ;
```

And there's nothing optional there.  One of those has to match.

You've already mentioned in your comments that you understand why moving the rule to its own rule -- that can potentially match an infinite number of empty strings -- is a bad, idea, so I won't belabor that here.

But why did the error go away when you did that?  Because

```
defines : '[Defines]'
         define_statement+
         | ('UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal)? // <<< HERE
         ;
```

is guaranteed to match *something*, even if it's only the token `[Defines]` , which is an implicit lexer token.  So even if the UEFI thing is empty string, there's still *something* to parse.  That wasn't true in the first version we examined; indeed the whole `define_statement` rule there could have been an empty string.  That's quite a difference from a parsing standpoint.

Now the big question:  Is the `[Defines]` section truly optional, or not?  Only you can answer that.  But if it is, perhaps you should just recode it as:

```
defines : ('[Defines]' define_statement+)?

define_statement  : 'INF_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal 
                  | 'BASE_NAME' EQ BaseName
                  | 'FILE_GUID' EQ RegistryFormatGUID
                  | 'MODULE_TYPE' EQ Edk2ModuleType
                  | 'UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal
```

This makes it completely optional.  Again, only you can decide if this is valid for your grammar and expected input.

Make sense?  I hope I helped you!

### EDIT 1

To relieve the error, try this grammar (I made explicit tokens for the test values to get it to run):

```
grammar Uefi;
defines : '[Defines]' statement+ ;
statement : define_statement | uefi_statement ;      
uefi_statement : 'UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal ;
define_statement  : 'INF_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal 
                  | 'BASE_NAME' EQ BaseName
                  | 'FILE_GUID' EQ RegistryFormatGUID
                  | 'MODULE_TYPE' EQ Edk2ModuleType
                  ;
// DUMMY VALUES               
SpecVersion_VersionVal : '0x00010005';
BaseName : 'WebServer';
RegistryFormatGUID : '99E87DCF-6162-40c5-9FA1-32111F5197F7';
Edk2ModuleType : 'SEC';
EQ : '=';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand why the `defines` rule in the second grammar *is guaranteed to match something*? `defines` rule still has 2 alternatives, one is non-empty and the other `UEFI...` string can **still** be empty. Please see my updated question.

Comment: `[Defines]`, as it is listed in single quotes, is what is referred to as an implied lexer token.  If present, it will be lexed.  As part of a parser rule, the rule will be parsed.  That may be the only thing there, depending on the scenarios I laid out, but if present it'll be parsed, hence no error message.  I've been through this before with grammars where almost everything is optional.  It's just a warning -- only we as language designers can say whether it's okay or not.

Comment: In my scenario, the `[Defines]` is mandatory, but **only** the `UEFI...` string line is optional. I am still trying to figure out a grammar for this.

Comment: @smwikipedia  If that's the case, then your original grammar was spot on.  Ignore the warning and just realize when you make your Listener or Visitor there may be nothing there to parse when you do your overrides, so check for content in the context before trying to parse something that might not be there.  Yours is a very common pattern.  Well done.

Comment: But that's an error not a warning. I am using ANTLR 4.7.  Please see my ADD 1 and 2.

Comment: @smwikipedia  You're right I didn't read that closely enough.  The "?" makes it optional and that's all.  When I read your original question about "warning" I had deja vu, been there many times.  Let me take a bit of a closer look, do you still need help or are you good to go now?  So the DEFINES section is mandatory (the header) and only optional one is the UEFI thing, and if present, there can be only one?

Comment: Yes, the [Defines] is mandatory. Only the UEFI thing is optional. And if it is present, there can be only one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150631/discussion-between-jlh-and-smwikipedia).

Comment: btw, have you tried when there's only the header `[DEFINES]`. Just curious. I have turned off my computer so I can only try it out tomorrow.

Comment: As I just tried it, in case of only the header `[DEFINES]` exists, simply change the `statement+` to `statement*` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just add my solution. Credit goes to @JLH.

The important thing to get is to have **2 separate rules** for lines with **different natures**.

- `linesGroup1_Defines`
- `linesGroup2_Defines`.

This way, the `optional nature` of a line can be reached through `|` (choice) instead of `?`(optional).

```
grammar inf;

start : configSections;

configSections: configSection+
                EOF;

configSection: section_Defines
             | bSection
             ;

section_Defines : '[Defines]'
                 sectionLine_Defines*;

sectionLine_Defines  : linesGroup1_Defines | linesGroup2_Defines;

linesGroup1_Defines : 'INF_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal 
           | 'BASE_NAME' EQ BaseName
           | 'FILE_GUID' EQ RegistryFormatGUID
           | 'MODULE_TYPE' EQ Edk2ModuleType
           ;
linesGroup2_Defines : 'UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal
              | 'PI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION' EQ SpecVersion_VersionVal
              ;


bSection : '[b]'
           SectionLine_b+;
```

(Some necessary token definitions are omitted for brevity)

[image]

### ADD 1

On a second thought, with the above solution, I didn't cover the semantic that `linesGroup1_Deines` is mandatory and `linsGroup2_Defines` is optional. **Actually both are optional now**. It can accept input with only optional lines like below:

```
[Defines]
  UEFI_SPECIFICATION_VERSION     = 0x00010005
```

I am not sure if this semantic **can/should** be covered in the grammar. Maybe I need to further refine it.